# Initialization functionality unavailable for this session, in google Ads

Tags: android, ads

I'm getting this error of google Ads, suddently. I can't find anything here with this error.

Notice that ads are displaying correctly

```
Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.
```

Comment: any solution you got?

Comment: Nothing at the moment

Comment: Ads got activated after 12hours in admob and not able to see above msgs.

Comment: Any one got the answer? It's been more then a week but i sill getting same error message

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting your test device? It worked for me. Also if you have other apps with admob try uninstalling them since numerous calls will be made leading to the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved this error by adding the following lines to my `onCreate` method:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
    }
});
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```